# Grails- How to query the list

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain classes like this

```
 Class Rules{
  List <Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>()
  // blah blah 
  static hasMany = [departments:Department]
 }

  Class Department {
     String name
  }


def listOfRules= // find the rules based on department selected
```

i am trying to get all the Rules which contains selected departments  .. so how can i query that..

this is grails application.. which uses hibernate .

Comment: You shouldn't declare the List<Department>. Having it in the static hasMany is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List departmentIds = []
// Code to populate departmentIds goes here

def rulesWithTestingDepartment = Rules.withCriteria {
  departments {
    'in'('id', departmentIds)
  }
}
```

Comment: from view i am passing the id of departmens(it can be 1 or multiple department) .. i want to get the rules which contains those deapartments

Comment: It should be 'departments'  instead of 'department' in the criteria